# Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function array-callback-return

Tags: javascript

I've seen similar questions here, but I can't quite figure out how to silence this error for my case with several conditions involved.

This is the `.filter()` object:

```
orders.filter((order) => {
  if (filterId === 0) {
    return order.status === 0 && order.type <= 3;
  } else if (filterId === 1) {
    return order.status === 0 && order.type === 0;
  } else if (filterId === 2) {
    return order.status === 0 && order.type === 1;
  } else if (filterId === 3) {
    return order.status === 0 && order.type === 2;
  }
}).map(...);
```

Comment: Make sure there's a `return` at the end of the `if else` sequence. What exactly is giving you this error?

Comment: All paths should return something; there's no path here for an unmatched `filterId`.

Comment: If these are all the possible `filterId` values, change the last `else if` to just `else`.

Comment: This seems like a lint warning, it shouldn't be an error. As far as `filter()` is concerned, not returning anything is equivalent to `return false;`.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, it fixed the warning.

Answer (score 0):

consider switch your approach to switch instead chain of if else.

```js
orders.filter((order) => {
  let value = 0;
  
  switch(filtedId){
    case 0:
      value = order.status === 0 && order.type <= 3;
    case 1:
      value = order.status === 0 && order.type === 0;
    case 2:
     value = order.status === 0 && order.type === 1;
    case 3:  
     value =order.status === 0 && order.type === 2;
    default: 
      value = 0
  }
  
  return value 
}).map(...);
```